# 404 Error when installing PHP5-Curl

Tags: ubuntu, curl

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.6.11 and running Apache/2.4.12.  I am trying to install/run Curl with PHP.  After running sudo apt-get update I run the following command and get 404 errors and bool(false) when I run  `var_dump(function_exists('curl_init')); print` from a php page. .

```
   sudo apt-get install php5-curl && echo $? 
        Reading package lists... Done 
        Building dependency tree 
        Reading state information... Done 
        The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required: 
        kde-l10n-engb 
        Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it. 
        The following NEW packages will be installed: 
        php5-curl 
        0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
        Need to get 30.0 kB of archives. 
        After this operation, 114 kB of additional disk space will be used. 
        WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated! 
        php5-curl 
        Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y 
        Err us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-updates/main php5-curl i386 5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3.4 
        404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80] 
        Err security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security/main php5-curl i386 5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3.4 
        404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80] 
        E: Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/… 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80] 

        E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I run `sudo find / -name curl.so\*` and get nothing and was told this means the module is still not installed.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is end of life, so maybe that means the package repositories are not maintained any more.

Comment: I'm installing PHP5 curl though?  I'm not sure the OS has anything to do with it as PHP5 runs on multiple version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco Karl is right. Ubuntu (maintained by Canonical software) no longer supports Ubuntu 12 and they have removed the url your apt command is trying to access. Here, you can see for yourself http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu%20wily-updates/main%20php5-curl

Comment: Got it, thanks guys.  Looks like an upgrade is in order.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

your package list is outdated and pointing to packages that no longer exist (usually happens because `foo5.1.1` was deleted when it was superseded by `foo5.1.2`) - just run `apt-get update` first, should fix the 404 problem.